# WordPress - Hide table rows on condition

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom CPT called Topics and only an editor or admin can create one. There are custom columns and custom meta box. It is only made for the backend purpose, not for publishing. So, it has a meta box and it will have a list of authors and selecting one will assign it to the author and will display in the name will be displayed in the table that has a custom column name Author. So, I want authors to see only those topics that has been assigned to them via meta box. Other Topics should be hidden. Is there a way to hide specific rows with the condition. 'cruiser_writer_value_key' will save the name of the author. So my condition is.

```
$writer_list_value = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'cruiser_writer_value_key', true );
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

if($current_user->display_name == $writer_list_value){
    //display post row
}

else{
    //hide post row of the column
    }
```

I'm really stuck in this. And Yeah I have custom columns too. It's just that I don't want to the author to edit or read Topics that have not been assigned to them.
So, my custom CPT is like this and the custom columns are there. See the picture for more details.
[image: Picture of the Topic CPT with custom Columns.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use filter_posts_list to filter the posts
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'filter_posts_list');

```
function filter_posts_list($query)
{
    //$pagenow holds the name of the current page being viewed
     global $pagenow, $typenow;  

     $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $allowed_roles = array('author');
        //Shouldn't happen for the admin, but for any role with the edit_posts capability and only on the posts list page, that is edit.php
        if(array_intersect($allowed_roles, $user->roles ) && ('edit.php' == $pagenow) &&  $typenow == 'your_custom_post_type')
        { 
        //global $query's set() method for setting the author as the current user's id
        $query->set(
        'meta_query', array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'yout_meta_key',
            'value'   => $user->display_name,
            'compare' => '==',
        ),
        )
        ); // here you can set your custom meta field using meta_query.
        }
}
```

Comment: Hey, really thanks for the reply but still have some problem. At first, I want to check if the user is author or editor or admin. If it is admin or editor, show all the post else if it is author than check the display name of the current author and if it is equal to the meta_value passed in the writer column of the post than show the post but if the value is different than hide that row. I know your answer can be correct but if you can explain more than it would be easy.

Comment: Hey, this works. But I just have a small problem. The author can't edit the post that has been assigned to them. They can see but can't do anything more. If this works then I'm all set. I would really be grateful to you. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Yes. Really but only for those that they are assigned to.

Comment: I think you have to make changes in user privileges, if you are using any plugin there must be options to authorize different privileges to different roles.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I already did some research found out that I have not given the author the capability to edit other's post. Since I only want the author to edit CPT but not the actual post. Is there a way to give the capability to the author to only edit others' CPT post but not the actual post? I tried to give the author capability to edit others' post but I need it only for my CPT. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please check the following links if they help you
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14553/allow-member-to-have-access-to-custom-post-type-only-permission-to-only-edit-th
and this
https://3.7designs.co/blog/2014/08/restricting-access-to-custom-post-types-using-roles-in-wordpress/

Comment: Thank You Very Much really appreciate it.